# rss feed for questions and answers that earn badges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, badges, feed

I'd like to be able to get and RSS feed for either/both questions and answers that earn a badge, filter by tag if possible.

As an example, all "nice answer" winning answers in questions with the tag "java" or all "great questions" tagged "ruby" and "metaprogramming"

EDIT:

This could also be accomplished by allowing searching for the posts with the most votes.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible, as our badge awarding process only returns (userid), (badgeid), (expected count). It does not return the posts.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff has said that the goal is to not make it readily apparent how a particular badge was earned, so you'll have a tough road to plow in convincing him, I'm afraid.